# multiplying vertex data causes uneven outline (shaderlab unity3d)

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, cg, shaderlab

I have created a simple outline shader in Unity3D's shader lab with two passes: pass one scales the object up by multiplying vertex information along a vertex normal and pass two draws the regular (base pass) version of the object. The problem is in the code for the outline pass:

```or-tag-here
Pass {
    Name "OUTLINE"

    ZWrite Off
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha // Normal

    CGPROGRAM
    #pragma vertex vert
    #pragma fragment frag
    #include "UnityCG.cginc"

    struct appdata {
        float4 vertex : POSITION;
        float3 normal : NORMAL;
    };

    struct v2f {
        float4 position : POSITION;
        float3 normal : NORMAL;
    };

    uniform float _OutlineWidth;
    uniform float4 _OutlineColor;

    v2f vert(appdata v) {
        v.vertex.xyz *=  _OutlineWidth;

        v2f o;
        o.position = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
        return o;
    }

    half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR {
        return _OutlineColor;
    }

    ENDCG
}
```

`_OutlineWidth` and `_OutlineColor` are of Range and Color types, respectively. I have applied this shader to a couple of "tetromino-like" meshes that have been created programmatically. The result is this (click on links):

[image one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhqnN.png) [image two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu8lb.png)

As you can see, an outline is created, but the outline is not *uniform width* along the outer edge of the object. Along one of the faces, the outline is larger--it is larger along the face that is furthest from the center of the shape. And with non-convex shapes the problem is magnified; outline may not even encompass the shape at all:

[image three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWX90.png)

I understand that this is due to the vertex position being relative to the center of the shape and that the line `v.vertex.xyz *=  _OutlineWidth` merely multiplies this position by a constant amount (putting it further away from the center of the object). How do I modify my code so that the outline pixels are calculated independent of the shape's center and with integrity to the true outline of the object?

Comment: As you already wrote you should push the vertices `along a vertex normal` and not directly multiplying their position as this scales them from the object center. So you should take the normal into account `v.vertex.xyz += v.normal *  _OutlineWidth;` It is important that the normal should be averaged for all vertices at the same position, else the faces will disconnect from each other.

Comment: How might I go about averaging the normals for all vértices of the same position? @Gnietschow

Comment: I never worked with you environment the shader lab, so I can only give you hints how I did it. You'll need to compute them at the creation of you models. When I needed a border shader, I added a second normal to all meshes while loading. Therefore I clustered all vertices with the same position, averaged their normals and stored it as a second normal in each vertex, which I later could use in the shader as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Gnietschow said, you need to use the "smooth normals" of those vertices to know the direction to expand the outline:

[image: hard vs smooth normals.]
Source: FrostSoft

One way to do this is to calculate the soft normals in C# and then assign them as vertex data. This example uses `uv2` and `uv3` channels to hold the smooth normal components:

```c#
Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;

Vector3[] meshVertices = mesh.vertices;
//map vertex positions to the ids of all vertices at that position
Dictionary<Vector3, List<int>> vertexMerge = new Dictionary<Vector3, List<int>>();
for(int i = 0; i < mesh.vertexCount; i++) {
    Vector3 vectorPosition = meshVertices[i];

    if(!vertexMerge.ContainsKey(vectorPosition)) {
        //if not already in our collection as a key, add it as a key
        vertexMerge.Add(vectorPosition, new List<int>());
    }

    //add the vertex id to our collection
    vertexMerge[vectorPosition].Add(i);
}

//map vertexIDs to the averaged normal
Vector3[] meshNormals = mesh.normals;
Vector3[] vertexAveragedNormals = new Vector3[mesh.vertexCount];

foreach (List<int> duplicatedVertices in vertexMerge.Values) {
    //calculate average normal
    Vector3 sumOfNormals = Vector3.zero;
    foreach (int vertexIndex in duplicatedVertices) {
        sumOfNormals += meshNormals[vertexIndex];
    }

    Vector3 averagedNormal = (sumOfNormals /= duplicatedVertices.Count).normalized; //average is sum divided by the number of summed elements

    //write the result to our output
    foreach (int vertexIndex in duplicatedVertices) {
        vertexAveragedNormals[vertexIndex] = averagedNormal;
    }
}


//write the result to mesh.
//x and y components shoved into uv3, z component shoved into uv4, with w component of 1.
Vector2[] vertexAveragedNormalsXY = new Vector2[mesh.vertexCount];
Vector2[] vertexAveragedNormalsZW = new Vector2[mesh.vertexCount];
for(int i = 0; i < mesh.vertexCount; i++) {
    Vector3 normal = vertexAveragedNormals[i];
    vertexAveragedNormalsXY[i] = new Vector2(normal.x, normal.y);
    vertexAveragedNormalsZW[i] = new Vector2(normal.z, 1);
}

mesh.uv3 = vertexAveragedNormalsXY;
mesh.uv4 = vertexAveragedNormalsZW;
```

Source: [Reddeyfish-](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/5zhi8x/outline_shader_has_unwanted_artifacts_when_using/dez6g0i/)

Then, you use TEXCOORD2 and TEXCOORD3 to reconstruct the smooth normals in `vert`. Use those to move your vertex position accordingly, while keeping the vertex normal the same hard normal for any lighting purposes:

```
Pass {
    Name "OUTLINE"

    ZWrite Off
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha // Normal

    CGPROGRAM
    #pragma vertex vert
    #pragma fragment frag
    #include "UnityCG.cginc"

    struct appdata {
        float4 vertex : POSITION;
        float3 normal : NORMAL;
        float4 texcoord2 : TEXCOORD2;
        float4 texcoord3 : TEXCOORD3;
    };

    struct v2f {
        float4 position : POSITION;
        float3 normal : NORMAL;
    };

    uniform float _OutlineWidth;
    uniform float4 _OutlineColor;

    v2f vert(appdata v) {
        // add the outline width in the direction of the shared normal
        float3 sharedNormal = float3(v.texcoord2.xy, v.texcoord3.x);

        v.vertex.xyz +=  _OutlineWidth * sharedNormal;  

        v2f o;
        o.position = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
        return o;
    }

    half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR {
        return _OutlineColor;
    }

    ENDCG
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, it took me a while to get around to implementing this. The code you gave works great, except for a few artifacts that occur when there are six normals all pointing orthogonally outward from one point, but is simple to fix. Thanks!